# Tableau Tab View

Tags: tableau-api

I have published Tableau dashboard with 3 views as one worksheet in sever. The action is set between the views and working perfectly in local desktop version. When i publish the same in server with Non Tab view(Means each view should be displayed in separate browser tab) it is not working. In the Published dashboard when i changed to Tab view it is working perfectly.

My customer wants to see each view in separate browser tab and not with in.

I dont understand what is the issue and how to resolve. Help me to resolve.

Comment: With the setup requirement you describe of on browser tab per worksheet, you will need to use the Javascript API and write event handlers to update other windows. Actions will only work when the workbook is displayed in the same browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using sheets in separate table, you might want to use URL actions.

You can also specify filters for reports in other sheets using the URL actions, refer to below link for more details on how to filter using URL parameters:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm

https://community.tableau.com/thread/104580